# Get url action in Application child class

Tags: php, url-routing

This function is in `Application` `class` > mvc > php

```
private function splitUrl()
{
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {

        // split URL
        $url = trim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        $this->url_controller = isset($url[0]) ? $url[0] : null;
        $this->url_action = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : null;
        unset($url[0], $url[1]);
        $this->url_params = array_values($url);
    }
}
```

**New edit**

I have this class

```
class Page extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

            //echo parent::splitUrl()->this->url_action;

         echo parent::$this->url_action;

    }
    public function index()
    {   
   // removed lins
    }
}
```

How to get **`$this->url_action`** in extends functions ?

Comment: can you show how/where the `url_action()` method is declared?

Comment: $this->url_action = isset($url[1]) ? $url[1] : null;

Comment: @iam-decoder it's the current action ! in mvc

Comment: @Jessica no i take short it

Comment: class has been edited !

Answer (score 0):

The field url_action should be protected (or public, but that's not recommend). So you can use this in child classes.

See below such as pseudoniem code:

In your parent:

```
class Foo
{
   protected $url_action = 'something'; // or set it via setter
}
```

The child class:

```
class FooChild extends Foo // Now, child can access protected (and public) fields of its parent!
{
   public function getFromParent()
   {
       return $this->url_action; // or what you want
   }

}
```

Comment: @danialdezfooli Henri's solution is correct; did you change the modifier of the variable declaration from `public` to `protected`? also, remove the `$this->` part of your echo statement.

Comment: @danialdezfooli It's important for you to understand the principe. That's why I've added the example code. Make sure that you have a protected variable in your parent. Otherwise: post your parent class code.

Comment: i found the problem :( the parent class is controller not aplication :D

Comment: @danialdezfooli That part did you not post. Do you understand my answer? That's more important to understand!